# Show 3d axes in Plotly, R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Using `plotly` in `R`, how do I make a 3d plot that shows the axes, like this:
[image]

instead of a plot that shows a bounding box, like this:
[image]

?

R code for the second is

```
t <- seq(0,2*pi,by =1)
r <- seq(0,1,by = .1)
x <- as.vector(outer(t,r,function(t,r).5*r*cos(t)))
y <- as.vector(outer(t,r,function(t,r)r*sin(t)))
z <- 4*x^2+y^2
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = "mesh3d", opacity=.5)
```

Comment: what is the code for the first plot ?

Comment: there is no code for the first plot, sadly.  it's an image from a textbook demonstrating the kind of output I would like.